# Laravel 5.4 Can't login the user

Tags: laravel, authentication

When I register new User, it logs in, but when I logout and try to login it just redirects me back to login page with custom error message 'Check your credentials again'. I can't figure out what's wrong.

[image: SessionController]
[image: RegisterController]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you are not hashing the password. In `RegistrationController` change your `store()` function like this.

```
use Hash;
class RegistrationContoller extends Controller
{
    ...
    public function store()
    {
        ...
        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => Hash::make($request->password) //<-- you were missing this.
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I just started fresh and re-built everything and got it right. Looks like there were some logical errors in my code. Thanks for the help with password encryption!